# SQL full text search even in small table incredible slow

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a simple user database table (mysql) which stores user-specific data like the `ID`, `name`, `passwordHash`, date of signup etc.

The `name` column is indexed with mysql fulltext to improve the search time. In the following example I wanted to use this fulltext index to filter out rows which don't match the search term at all (= Rough and fast filtering). Due to the fact that I need a 1:1 match I appended a second condition to compare the `name` value directly to my search term (= Exact and slow filtering).

So to clarify: I need to find an exact match in the table and because `name = "searchTerm"` is slow of course I wanted to use the fulltext index first to sort out most rows first.

```
SELECT passwordHash, ID
FROM Users
WHERE
   MATCH(name) AGAINST('Flutter+User' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
   AND LOWER(name) = LOWER('Flutter-User')
LIMIT 1
```

Unfortunately this query is unbelievable slow and I don't understand why: it took 107.47ms for a table with just 100 (!) rows.

When removing the fulltext search condition and therefore just executing

```
SELECT passwordHash, ID
FROM Users
WHERE  LOWER(name) = LOWER('Flutter-User')
LIMIT 1
```

it takes less than 1ms. Am I doing something wrong here?
Any answer would be highly appreciated.

Added more information for better analysis:

```
CREATE TABLE `Users` (
 `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `passwordHash` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `name_index` (`name`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `email_index` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=200003 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

`EXPLAIN` (the first query) returns:

[image]

`EXPLAIN` (the second query) returns:

[image]

Comment: I'm not 100% up on this stuff yet, especially for MySql, so just a comment. Anyway, there's a penalty for opening a full-text index, but it's a _constant_ penalty. That is, you have 107ms (still just a ~1/10th second) to get into the index vs 1ms without for 100 rows. But as the number of rows increase, that full-text lookup should _stay_ a reasonably near 107ms, while the time for the other query will increase much more as rows increase.

Comment: [cont]. You may also have a situation where MySql has the table already loaded in memory, but the index was still out on disk. That's common for testing/development scenarios. If so, you can see this by running a very similar query again right away, and it will be faster the second time now the index is loaded in memory.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Thanks for your comment. 1) Yeah this could be a possible answer but not a very satisfying one haha. 2) That is actually not the case because I did run the exact same query multiple times and it took always that long.

Comment: PLease consider posting A) SHOW CREATE TABLE users; and B) EXPLAIN SELECT (your first query); and C) EXPLAIN SELECT (your second query); for analysis.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Added 

Comment: I have absolut no idea why a concrete search for a name in the table should be slow if you setup an standard index on the name. Maybe I miss something in your explanation why you need the full text search but I cannot see any reason for it

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff I thought full text is the only way to get a text column indexed with mySQL and InnoDB? If another type of index for text values is also possible I am of course open to it.

Comment: Give name just a simple index. That’s all

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff Just tried it out and this works a lot better and much faster (took only 0.7 ms in my test with 5 million rows). Thank you so much. If you want to get the karma you are free to write this as a short answer and I'll accept it. :-)

Comment: Your welcome. Don’t need the karma but thanks for the proposal

Comment: @Flexi          Please post current SHOW CREATE TABLE users;  so we can see your solution.  Thank You.

Comment: @WilsonHauck It is already added to the question (the code block above the two screenshots) but it doesn't matter anymore because Claus Bönnhoff already gave the right hint in the comment section here.

Comment: Have you not CREATED another index since the SHOW CREATE TABLE users; was posted?

Comment: @WilsonHauck Now I get what you mean. Yeah exactly. I'll write the answer myself. Just a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a hint in the comments I found out I used the wrong index type. After changing

```
FULLTEXT KEY `name_index` (`name`),
FULLTEXT KEY `email_index` (`email`)
```

to

```
INDEX KEY `name_index` (`name`),
INDEX KEY `email_index` (`email`)
```

I am now able to execute the query

```
SELECT passwordHash, ID
FROM Users
WHERE name = $searchTerm
LIMIT 1
```

a lot faster even if the tables are larger (<1ms with 5M rows).